# How do I use while loops to create a multiplication table?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

This is my code, it outputs a multiplication table but it's not what I wanted!

```
 num = int(input("Multiplication using value? : "))
 
while num <= 10:
    i = 1
    while i <= num:
        product = num*i
        print(num, " * ", i, " = ", product, "\n")
        i = i + 1
    print("\n")
    num = num + 1
```

I am basically creating a multiplication table from the user's input from 1-9.

Ex. If the user inputs "3",
I should get this output:

```
1*1=1
1*2=2
1*3=3

2*1=2
2*2=4
2*3=6

3*1=3
3*2=6
3*3=9
```

Comment: What does it do that is not what you wanted?

Comment: @khelwood It prints the table up to 10, but instead I want it to print the table up to the user input as given in the example

Comment: It will help people to understand your question if you include your _actual output_ in your question as well as your expected output.

Answer (score 4):

The reason why you have an infinite loop on your hands is because you are comparing `i` to `num`, while also increasing `num` on every run. If you make sure `i` is always `<= 10`, you get your desired output:

```
while num <= 10:
    i = 1
    while i <= 10:
        product = num*i
        print(num, " * ", i, " = ", product, "\n")
        i = i + 1
    num = num + 1
    print("\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

Even if the code you posted is not pythonic at all (it is very close to what could be written in C language), it nearly works: with minimum modifications, it can be fixed as follows to give your expected ouput:

```
numInput = int(input("Multiplication using value? : "))
num = 1

while num <= numInput:
    i = 1
    while i <= numInput:
        product = num*i
        print(num, " * ", i, " = ", product)
        i = i + 1
    print("")  # no need to add explicit newline character because it is automatically added
    num = num + 1
```

In a more pythonic way, you can also do the following:

```
numInput = int(input("Multiplication using value? : "))

for i in range(1,numInput+1):
    for j in range(1,numInput+1):
        print(i, " * ", j, " = ", i*j)
    print("")
```

Answer (score 2):

For this problem it's easier to use for loops.

```
num = int(input("Multiplication using value? : "))

for left in range(1,num+1):  # 1st loop
    for right in range(1,num+1): # 2nd loop (nested)
        print(left, " * ", right, " = ", left * right)
    print() # newline
```

To understand this problem, look at the two multiplicands: left and right.

**Left multiplicand** goes from (1-->num), hence the first for loop.

Then, for each value of the left multiplicand, the **right multiplicand** goes from (1-->num), hence the 2nd loop is nested inside the first loop.

Answer (score 1):

You've lots of logical error. Please have a look at this updated code:

```
num = int(input("Multiplication using value : "))

i=1 #you haven't initialized this variable
while i <=num:
    j=1
    while j <= num:
        product = i*j #updated
        print(i, " * ", j, " = ", product, "\n") #updated
        j = j + 1
    print("\n")
    i = i + 1
```

Output (for input 3):

```
1  *  1  =  1 

1  *  2  =  2 

1  *  3  =  3 



2  *  1  =  2 

2  *  2  =  4 

2  *  3  =  6 



3  *  1  =  3 

3  *  2  =  6 

3  *  3  =  9
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.6+, you can use f-strings with a nested `for` loop:

```
num = int(input("Multiplication using value? : "))

for i in range(1, num+1):
    for j in range(1, num+1):
        print(f'{i} * {j} = {i*j}')

Multiplication using value? : 3
1 * 1 = 1
1 * 2 = 2
1 * 3 = 3
2 * 1 = 2
2 * 2 = 4
2 * 3 = 6
3 * 1 = 3
3 * 2 = 6
3 * 3 = 9
```

Answer (score 1):

multiplication table using while loop in python

```
num = int(input("enter the number= "))
i = 1

while i<=10:
    print(num, "X", i, "=", num * i)
    i = i+1
```

output

```
enter the number= 33
33 X 1 = 33
33 X 2 = 66
33 X 3 = 99
33 X 4 = 132
33 X 5 = 165
33 X 6 = 198
33 X 7 = 231
33 X 8 = 264
33 X 9 = 297
33 X 10 = 330
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

```
num = int(input("Enter the number: "))
i = 1

print("Mulltiplication of number:", num)

while i<=10:
    print(f"{num}X{i}={num*i}")
    i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiplication table 1 to 10

```
for x in range(1,11):
  for y in range(1,11):
    print(x*y, end='\t')
  print()
  print()
```

Comment: The question is about "How to use `while` loop" while you propose an answer based on `for`. If you think that it is not possible solve the problem by using `while` loops you should explain the rationale otherwise you should propose an answer unsing `for` loop. If it is the case, you can explain why wsing `while` loop could be, for example, inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

input any number to get your normal multiple table(Nomenclature) in 10 iterate times.

```
num = int(input("Input a number: ")) 
# use for loop to iterate 10 times
for i in range(1,11):
   print(num,'x',i,'=',num*i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num = int(input('Enter the number you want the multiplication table for:'))
i=1
while i<=10:
product = num*i
print(product)
i=i+1 

print('Thank you')
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a multiplication table using `while` loop is shown below:

```
b =  int(input('Enter the number of the multiplicaction table : '))

print('The multiplication table of '+ str(b) + 'is : ')

a=0

while a<=11:
    a=a+1
    c= a*b
    print( str(b)+' x '+str(a)+' ='+str(c))

print('done!!!!')
```

Answer (score -1):

To create a multiplication table in python:

```
name=int(input("Enter the number of multiplication"))

i=1
  
while(i<=10):

print(str(name)+"X"+str(i)"="+str(name*i))

i=i+1
```