# I want to create a multiplication table in Swift but I am presented with the following error

Tags: swift, for-loop

I refererred to these posts:
1. [Multiplication table in Swift ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37068553/multiplication-table-in-swift-ios)
2. [How do I use while loops to create a multiplication table in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51187314/how-do-i-use-while-loops-to-create-a-multiplication-table-in-python)

In the second one they use a while loop but I imagine that I could use a for loop too. Could you suggest where I am going wrong in my code?

```
import Foundation

let i = 2

let multiplier = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

for a in multiplier {
   product = i * a

   print("/(product)")
}
```

I am getting the following error when I run it in my terminal.

Error code:

> no_name.swift:13:5: error: use of unresolved identifier 'product'
>
> product = i * a
>
> ^~~~~~~
>   Darwin.mprotect:1:13: note: did you mean 'mprotect'?
>
> public func mprotect(_: UnsafeMutableRawPointer!, _: Int, _: Int32) ->
>
> Int32 ^
>
> CoreServices.pConduit:1:12: note: did you mean 'pConduit'?

Comment: `let product = I * a`. Please spend some time reading the [Swift Programming Language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/index.html) book.

Comment: I have tried: let product i * a. I know that we must first declare the object as a variable or constant. But I am still presented with an error. Here is the error for that:
no_name.swift:13:9: warning: initialization of immutable value 'product' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it
   
 let product = i * a

 ~~~~^~~~~~~
    _
/(product)
/(product)
/(product)
/(product)
/(product)
/(product)
/(product)
/(product)
/(product)
/(product)

Comment: Fix your `print` statements. Read about string interpolation in the Swift book. You need `\(....)`, not `/(....)`.

Comment: @rmaddy Oops! I am sorry that was very silly mistake on my part. I completely overlooked that. 

Thanks its working now. I think this should be marked as an answer. 

Any how I consider this question **CLOSED** and sorry for such a silly mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I would write this as a comment but I dont have enough reputation to do so: You forgot to declare your variable, you just say `product = i * a`

But you have to declare it as `let product = i*a`

Also you can declare it out of your for loop as `var product = 1` and then you can use it in your for loop as `product = i*a`

Comment: This isn't a loop invariant. It's better to keep it scoped within the loop.

Comment: Don't needlessly declare a variable in the wrong scope.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a variable `product` which has never been declared. The compiler is trying to guess what you meant, and is suggesting some similar names for you.